# HTML5 block-quote with author

Tags: html, quote

Hi I'm seeing a great number of different ways to implementat `blockquote` in html but it doesn't seem clear in its documentation how should I properly format a `blockquote` *let's say* of a famous quote and metion its author like:

> In victory, you deserve Champagne, in defeat, you need it.
>
> Napoleon Bonaparte

What would the correct format of that be in HTML5?

Should the author be inside or outside the `blockquote` tag?
Should it be inside the `cite` attribute? (even knowing the documentation specifies an URI , not author)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://neilpie.co.uk/2011/12/13/html5-quote-attribution/

For example, use

```
<small class="author">Napoleon Bonaparte<small>
```

HTML 5 documentation says, "Small print typically features disclaimers, caveats, legal restrictions, or copyrights. Small print is also sometimes used for attribution, or for satisfying licensing requirements."

Comment: Could you add a link to the HTML 5 documentation for the quote?

Comment: It doesn't seems to say that anymore as you can see, here is what the W3C is saying about it: `The small element represents so-called “fine print” or “small print”, such as legal disclaimers and caveats.`   

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/small.html

Answer (score 63):

I googled about this and it looks like `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` should do the job:

```
<figure>
  <blockquote cite="https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/html/figure.html">
    Quotes, parts of poems can also be a part of figure.
  </blockquote>
  <figcaption>MDN editors</figcaption>
</figure>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/html/figure.html

```
<figure>
  <blockquote cite="http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element">
    The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a caption,
    that is self-contained and is typically referenced as a single unit from the
    main flow of the document.
  </blockquote>
  <figcaption>asdf</figcaption>
</figure>
```

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element

Comment: Thanks very much- this is extremely helpful. Seems to be a lot of confusion out there surrounding a seemingly simple question.

Answer (score 23):

**UPDATE 2020**

WHATWG says about the [blockquote element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element)

> Attribution for the quotation, if any, must be placed outside the
> blockquote element.

WHATWG says about the [cite element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element)

> The cite element represents the title of a work (e.g. a book, a paper,
> [...])

> A person's name is not the title of a work [...] and the element must
> therefore not be used to mark up people's names.

So the following HTML it's fine:

```
<blockquote>
 <p>In victory, you deserve Champagne, in defeat, you need it.</p>
</blockquote>
<p>— Napoleon Bonaparte</p>
```

**OLD POST 2018**

HTML 5.3 Editor’s Draft, 9 March 2018

W3C says about the [cite element](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-cite-element):

> The cite element represents a reference to a creative work. It must
> include the **title** of the work or the **name** of the author (person,
> people or organization) or an URL reference, or a reference in
> abbreviated form as per the conventions used for the addition of
> citation metadata.

So the following HTML it's fine:

```
<blockquote>
    Those who pass by us, do not go alone, and do not leave us alone; 
    they leave a bit of themselves, and take a little of us.
    <cite>Antoine de Saint-Exupéry</cite>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Just want to note that `<cite>` should not be used here. `A citation is not a quote (for which the q element is appropriate).`

Comment: Thank you @jsun, you're right. The specification has changed and I have already updated the post.

Answer (score 18):

This is how Bootstrap does [quotes in v3.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type-blockquotes).

```
<blockquote>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <footer>Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```

More on the footer element from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer

> The HTML `<footer>` Element represents a footer for its nearest
>   sectioning content or sectioning root element (i.e, its nearest parent
>   `<article>, <aside>, <nav>, <section>, <blockquote>, <body>, <details>,
>   <fieldset>, <figure>, <td>`). A footer typically contains information
>   about the author of the section, copyright data or links to related
>   documents.

You may also consider using [Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data), such as microdata, RDFa, and microformats.

Comment: It is invalid, documentation says that cite shoudnt be a person's name

Comment: @YannChabot like this: `<footer>Author Name, <cite title="Book Name">Book Name</cite></footer>`

Comment: You are right, they changed the documentation, back then they said that cite couldn't be used to cite a person, now you can

Answer (score 0):

My preference and it validates...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Blockquote Test</title></head>
<body>

<div style="width:300px;border:1px solid #cecece; padding:10px;">

<blockquote cite="URL">
In victory, you deserve Champagne, in defeat, you need it.
</blockquote>
<div class="credit" style="text-align:right;">
<cite><a href="URL">Napoleon Bonaparte</a></cite>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) says, a cite element must not contain a person's name.

Comment: <cite> is for "citing" the title, not the author :)

Comment: So then how do you cite the author?

Comment: @JosephMansfield 3 years later it looks like the specification has changed: "*The cite element represents a reference to a creative work. It must include the title of the work **or the name of the author(person, people or organization)** or an URL reference, which may be in an abbreviated form as per the conventions used for the addition of citation metadata.*"

Comment: @h2ooooooo Following the current status of the [W3 page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/cite.html#cite-changes), it has still changed and can't be used anymore to refer to a person. But following the [this other W3 page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element), it can still be used.

Comment: @meduz' Look at the root urls: the latter is from 2014 while the former is from 2013. Also the former says: `"This document has been discontinued and is only made available for historical purposes. For an up to date reference on HTML elements (and more) please consult Web Platform Docs."`

Comment: Thanks you, Andre, I wasn't aware of the existence of the Web Platform Docs. By the way, the page [about blockquote](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/blockquote) refers to the [official W3 documentation page](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) which was last updated exactly the same day (2014-10-28) of the first link of my previous message. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This can be covered by Bootstrap 4 [`<footer class="blockquote-footer">`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/content/typography/#naming-a-source) element:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<blockquote class="blockquote">
  <p>In the digital age, knowledge is our lifeblood. And documents are the DNA of knowledge.</p>
  <footer class="blockquote-footer">Rick Thoman, CEO, <cite title="Xerox Corporation">Xerox</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```